# JSF application : should I use micro-services and how?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, jsf, jakarta-ee, microservices

I have a web application developed with JSF 2 and primefaces. The project has been frozen for months, but it's quite advanced, the whole application run inside the same container under glassfish, so it's a monolith.

My application has an user interface and its purpose is to offer them the possibility to organize urls to tutorials (any kinds) as cards, with tags for the classification, into folders. So any user has its own tree, they can make a research inside the other users's tree create a link on a file in their own tree, copy a entire folder, reorganize it etc.

Nowedays we hear a lot about microservices, Spring boot, Angular Js, react etc. I like to develop with JSF it's a great framework, but I'm asking myself about refactoring my application, at least the necessary parts into microservices, and if JSF is appropriate for that or if I should user other tools.

What I like for example with JSF is the facility to create views, its component approach, and how it handle the full cycle of a request.

For example with a simple folder creation form :

I have to choose the parent folder, so I can bind a research component to a backing bean that makes a research indirectly in my DB using a DAO ( in my app an EJB using JPA). That happens at the "invoke application" phase and refresh my form list with ajax at the end. When I submit the form I can also bind a converter to the research component to retrieve directly a Folder object, the converter uses also a DAO to retrieve the object that I need at the "Invoke application" phase to finish the job.

I also use validators to control different attributes of a new folder, usually I declare them inside my entity class (Folder, User ...) with annotations like @NotNull etc. Before I save the folder on my db, I also check the user rights to see if he can write inside the parent folder and so on. I do that inside the backing bean, so at the 'invoke application' phase, and return a faces message if anything happens wrong.

When I read about micro-services I see that you can use them directly inside a form using json for communication, so it seems quite different. For example if I have a micro-service for the CRUD operations of my folders, are the validators, the converters, part of the service or are they stand alone services ? And what about the security checks ? that kind of architecture is quite mysterious to me.

ps : English is not my mother tongue so be indulgent please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJs is pretty ancient man :)

You have to look at the pain points to identify ways to tear down your monolith. Monolith pains are usually slow and painful dev cycle and difficult manual test phases. If you did the entire arquillian thing and have full continuouos integration with single button deployments, you've slain the beast the hard way. Not many braved this route. But if you're looking at mounting feature creep with code freezes and manual test cycles then yeah you kind of want to try to pull some of those features out into a service you can redeploy very quickly

Comment: But this all is independent of JSF, SpringBoot, angular(js), reactjs or whatever... OP should read about microservices in general without the 'api' (json/rest) relation.

Comment: Lev Kuznetsov, thanks for your answer. I definitely need to learn more about micro-services.

Comment: Kukeltje, if these tools are independants from microservices, If I use microservices in my JSF application it cannot be on client side but only server side right ? With a javascript framework like Angular or React I could use microservices directly from the client side, isn't that the most  difference ?

Comment: well apparently there is no answer to these questions

Comment: And if you split things up in too much services, you have to start mocking each of these services in each of the service that is using them. Making things more complex in another way or start creating integration tests in a different way... In one way or another, complex applications (functionality wise) are... well... complex. SImple applications do not need to be split up in (micro) services and hence are... well... simple. All not JSF or angular or spring or whatever related. Hence there is no answer

Comment: actually with spring boot it's not that complex and you can create a simple application using micro-services.